# What is `iedit-apply-global-modification` for and how to use it?

Tags: iedit

The docstring says

```
"Apply last global modification."
```

But I am not sure what is it for and how to use it. I did not find any relevant information after a Google search.

Comment: Is that from a package you have installed? Have you read the documentation that came with it?

Comment: Yes, it is from `iedit` and the I've posted the documentation of it in the question and I don't get it. I also can not find any relate information from Google and its repo.

Comment: You’ve included the docstring for that one specific function, which is certainly pretty terse. But what about the rest of the documentation. Does it have a readme file? Does it have an info manual that shows up when you type `C-h i`? Does it at least have any comments in the source code? Usually packages will have some explanatory paragraphs at the top of their source code even if they have nothing else.